# Mail contacts in exchange are not showing in distribution lists on the client side

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, distribution-lists, contacts

I have an exchange 2013 server.
We have mail contacts set up for some external contacts.

There are several distribution lists which contain these mail contacts.

When an internal user inspects the distribution list through outlook, the mail contacts are not shown.

When I open exchange shell and run

> Get-DistributionGroupMember "MyGroupName"

I get the full list of users including the mail contacts.

[image]

[image]

I have checked the contacts and none of them are set to 'hide from address lists'.

Does anyone know how to include these recipients in the list as far as outlook is concerned?

The following is an output of get-mailcontact...

[image]

Comment: Can you run a get-mailcontact and share the ouput please? Also, does the problem manifest itself in OWA? Can you view the contact in the GAL OK? Does the name resolve properly if you type it into the To: field? Thanks

Comment: See my edit above for output of get-mailcontact.

Comment: The name does resolve properly when entered in the To: field, but doesn't seem to appear on the GAL, despite the recipient filter on the GAL being set to include mailcontacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just on a fluke, I managed to solve this issue... Thanks to LeMoore, as his comment sent me down the right path. 
Once I realised I couldn't see the mail contacts in the GAL that got me thinking...

This is a multi-tenant mail server and isolation is achieved using filters and customattribute1.

When the mailcontacts were created, as there is no option for customattribute1, It appears that my colleagues never set it.

I applied the correct value to customattribute1 via the shell and hey presto, suddenly the users can see the mailcontacts in the GAL and they appear in the distribution lists.

Thanks for the assistance guys!